# How to get the row position based on column value if dataframe has been resorted?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe has been resorted so the index values have lost their sequence.

In this example below, when I select for df_ranking.Ticker == 'WRB ', I want to get 0 instead of 478.

```
In [113]: df_ranking.head()
Out[113]: 
    Ticker TrendScoreStr  TrendScoreNum
478    WRB         GCAGA  2000100000200
259   ISRG         CMAMA  2000100000000
18    ALGN         DGAGA  2000001000200
106   CINF         GADMA  2000001000100
450    TRV         GADMA  2000001000100
```

Comment: `df_ranking.reset_index(drop=True).Ticker =='WRB'`

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
In [1788]: df_ranking.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)    
In [1789]: df_ranking                                     
Out[1789]: 
  Ticker TrendScoreStr  TrendScoreNum
0    WRB         GCAGA  2000100000200
1   ISRG         CMAMA  2000100000000
2   ALGN         DGAGA  2000001000200
3   CINF         GADMA  2000001000100
4    TRV         GADMA  2000001000100

In [1790]: df_ranking[df_ranking.Ticker.eq('WRB')] 
Out[1790]: 
  Ticker TrendScoreStr  TrendScoreNum
0    WRB         GCAGA  2000100000200
```